# Getting a Week View using angular bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to use Datepicker (ui.bootstrap.datepicker). But the view that I was is just one row with 7 days, representing one week. Basically I want to view one week at a time -- See second image.

The current DatePicker directive shows the following:
[image: entire month view]

But what I want is to show on week at a time.

[image: one week view]

I looked through `uib-datepicker` settings (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepicker) but could not find where to set the limit in number of weeks. In the `datepickerMode` where I select `day` it shows that one see 6-week calendar view, but I can't find in the options how to limit to 1-week.

Which option setting am I missing? Any pointers would be appreciated!

*Update*: I you have suggestions for another library to use that support week views. Feel free to also add a comment!
Thanks!

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think this is possible, from the doc link you posted:

> `day` - In this mode you're presented with a **6-week** calendar for a specified

I dont think this component supports showing only one week. There is no such option in the docs.